# Initialization order while calling new on a static field in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, static, initialization

I was practicing for my Java exam when I've came across this example:

```
class A1 {
    static {
        System.out.println("A1S");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new A3();
    }

}

class A2  {
    static {
        System.out.println("A2S");
    }

    public A2() {
        System.out.println("A2");
    }

    static A3 as = new A3();
}

class A3 extends A2 {
    static {
        System.out.println("A3S");
    }

    public A3() {
        System.out.println("A3");
    }
}

class A4 extends A3 {
    public A4() {
        super();
        System.out.println("A4");
    }
}
```

I was expecting the following output:

```
A1S
A2S
A3S
A2
A3
A2
A3
```

But I've received this output:

```
A1S
A2S
A2
A3
A3S
A2
A3
```

Shouldn't the static block in A3 be executed before the constructor output?
The [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1) says :

> Initialization of a class consists of executing its static initializers and the initializers for static fields (class variables) declared in the class.
>    A class or interface type T will be initialized immediately before
>   the first occurrence of any one of the following:
>
> T is a class and an instance of T is created.
>
> T is a class and a static method declared by T is
>   invoked.
>
> A static field declared by T is assigned.
>
> A static field declared by T is used and the field is not a constant
>   variable (§4.12.4).
>
> T is a top level class (§7.6), and an assert statement (§14.10)
>   lexically nested within T (§8.1.3) is executed.
>
> A reference to a static field (§8.3.1.1) causes initialization of only the class or interface that actually declares it, even though it might be referred to through the name of a subclass, a subinterface, or a class that implements an interface

Comment: `static A3 as = new A3()`